# Unable to access the resource from Tomcat server in windows

Tags: java, tomcat

On machine1, I installed apache tomcat 7 listening on port 9999 and copied a sample.html file in ../webapps/dummy folder of tomcat machine.I was able to access the resource with URL `http://localhost:9999/dummy/sample.html`

On machine2, Tomcat is already part of some product listening on port 8080 which i thought of utilising it for my sample test. So, I copied a sample.html file in ../webapps/dummy folder of tomcat machine. I was unable to access the resource with URL `http://localhost:8080/dummy/sample.html`

On machine2, I have existing servlet programming modules running in another folder ../webapps/xyz.

My question:

I am trying to understand, What are the list of things that i need to verify on machine, which let me know, why i have an issue in accessing the URL(above) on machine2? Is this something to do with http access configuration like basic.user/basic.groups file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has nothing to do with the port on which tomcat is running.

Did you restart Tomcat after copying file over? It might be that on machine2 it's not configured to run in a dev mode so it doesn't pick up changes at runtime.

or

(if this is linux/unix/mac computer) Tomcat on machine2 is running as tomcat:tomcat user, but file you copied can't be read by this user. Change the permissions of the file.

HTH,
Jan